# transferring drupal site from one domain to another?

Tags: theming, installation, 7

I have two domains: domain1.com & domain2.com

In my FTP folder, I have a folder inside my root folder which is named "home"

I installed and developed my site as domain1.com/home

Now I want to point domain2.com to the site files in the folder 'home'. I copied the files over, and when I now access domain2.com/home -- site comes up without CSS or any theming, clicking on node information gives "Internal Server Error"

Any ideas how this can be solved?

I have tried setting $base_url = 'http://www.domain2.com' in my settings.php (it was not set earlier), but that did not help - what else can I do?

Comment: maybe you could describe the process in brief (like modules used) which you followed to transfer the site from one domain to other?

Comment: Can you log in to domain2.com/user ?  If so, do that and flush all caches to start.

Comment: @indrock - I did not use any modules to transfer the site, I simply copied all the files. Should I be using something?

Comment: @nedwardss - nope, not able to log in. Gives Internal error.

Comment: @user1406716: Do it manually then. Jump into PHPMyAdmin or similar and TRUNCATE/empty all the tables starting with `cache_`.

Comment: @user1406716 : how did you backup your the database from `domain1.com` to `domain2.com`?

Comment: All - I did it manually, and pointing to the database directly from settings.php. Working for me now, thank you all very.